# Classification vs regression for binary response variables

Tags: regression, self-study, classification

I have a breast cancer dataset with ~30 predictors, all of which are continuous/numeric. The response variable is binary (the diagnosis is either malignant or benign). I know classification is good for cases where the responses are categorical and non-ordinal, but would regression suit this situation better, since it's along the lines of success/failure?

Comment: "Success/failure" is certainly non-ordinal and categorical, so I'd go with classification.

Comment: The min and the max can be changed if you are looking for a shifted and scaled beta. Is that what you are looking for? Unfortunately, there are still infinitely many different pairs of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that will give you a given mode between the min and the max, see the formula for the mode at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

Comment: You should look into logistic regression, search this site!